# UnicodeEncoding in java

Tags: java, c#, android, unicode, encoding

I have a string like that "QQBkADEBbgAxAXoA" I am creating a byte array of the string and using this code to convert it to string in c#.

```
string value = new UnicodeEncoding()).GetString(array)
```

I need this UnicodeEncoding in java. Is there a class that can perform it in java?

Answer (score 4):

C# class `UnicodeEncoding` encodes on UTF-16.

```
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
```

The code above worked for me, since c# was using little endian representation, and Java UTF-16 is big endian.

Answer (score 2):

The C# class [`UnicodeEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) encodes the string using the UTF-16 encoding.

In Java you should be able to convert the bytes back to a string like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;

String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-16");
```

Or the other way around, convert a Java string to bytes using UTF-16 encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("UTF-16");
```